# C++ struct in separate header file

Tags: c++, struct, codeblocks, header-files

I've tried to organize my project so I thought that I will include all of my global variables, #includes and struct definition in a global.h header. However I can't fully understand this concept and the errors during build seem to prove that. When i try to access my global.h in logic.h this is what happens.

global.h:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H
#include "logic.h"
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "graphics.h"

//Global variables and structs
enum directions
{
    D_UP,
    D_LEFT,
    D_DOWN,
    D_RIGHT,
    D_TOTAL
};

struct Character
{
    float health;
    float x;
    float y;
    float velocity;
    bool collision[D_TOTAL];
    directions direction;
    SDL_Rect animation;
    SDL_Rect sprite;
};

const int windowWidth = 800;
const int windowHeight = 600;
const int frameWidth = 64;
const int frameHeight = 64;
#endif // GLOBAL_H
```

logic.h:

```
#include "global.h"
//Header for gamelogic functions

//Initialization of all variables for a new character
void initCharacter(Character &newCharacter, float x, float y, directions startingDirection);
```

When i try to build it this is the error I'm getting:

```
||=== Build: Debug in GameProject0.2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\GameProject0.2\GameProject0.2\logic.h|5|error: variable or field 'initCharacter' declared void|
C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\GameProject0.2\GameProject0.2\logic.h|5|error: 'Character' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\GameProject0.2\GameProject0.2\logic.h|5|error: 'newCharacter' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\GameProject0.2\GameProject0.2\logic.h|5|error: expected primary-expression before 'float'|
C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\GameProject0.2\GameProject0.2\logic.h|5|error: expected primary-expression before 'float'|
C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\GameProject0.2\GameProject0.2\logic.h|5|error: 'directions' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 6 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I am not sure what I'm missing. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `include "global.h"`, one of the *first* things it says is `include "logic.h"`, so the processor opens that file, finds an `include "global.h"`, which does nothing because of the include guard, then it finds `void initCharacter(Character &newCharacter,` and gets confused because it doesn't yet know what a `Character` is. Then it returns from that include, lexes `enum directions`, then *finally* lexes `struct Character`, so *then* it knows what a `Character` is, far too late.

In general, try to make sure includes only go one way. Make sure `logic` includes `global`, or that `global` includes `logic`, but not both.

Or, if you're really lazy, there's a trick that sometimes sidesteps the issue: Put function and class definitions before the includes, as often as possible. Then `global` will tell the compiler that `class Character` exists, then when it includes `logic.h`, it won't have an issue.

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

enum directions;
struct Character; //If you're really lazy, this usually works

#include "logic.h"
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "graphics.h"

//Global variables and structs
enum directions
{
    D_UP,
    D_LEFT,
    D_DOWN,
    D_RIGHT,
    D_TOTAL
};

struct Character
{
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think that it clearly says #include "global.h" in logic.h file. I thought that this will do the job but somehow it doesn't :(

Comment: @RafałMyśliwczyk you've also included logic.h in global.h file. What do you think happens when you include logic.h which includes global.h which includes logic.h which includes global.h which includes logic.h which includes global.h which includes logic.h which includes global.h which includes logic.h which includes global.h which includes logic.h which includes global.h which includes logic.h which includes global.h which includes logic.h which includes global.h which includes logic.h which includes global.h which includes logic.h which includes global.h which includes logic.h ...?

Comment: A good cautionary tale about both avoiding circular dependencies and using [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). Two for the price of one.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. It seemes that once I separated the .h so it only includes the struct definition and I get all my includes from somewhere else it all works now.

Comment: @RafałMyśliwczyk: I failed to notice the circular dependency. Total fail on my end. Rewrote answer to discuss that instead.